# Modify Rviz fixed frame from ros node

Tags: ros, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to interact with a rviz UI which is running as a rqt pluging inside a bigger GUI. Basically, I need to change the "fixed frame" when some event is triggered.

I know that using `librviz` you can greatly interact with rviz, but that requieres that the rviz UI is created and launched programatically from the interacting node, which is not the case (the rviz UI is already running as a separate QT plugin).

Is there any way of modifying the configuration of rviz from a remote node? Is it possible at all for a ROS node to interact with rviz through topics or services?

Thank you and best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204149/modify-rviz-fixed-frame-from-ros-node/) by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 329 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but programmatically controlling camera viewpoint (and animating it) is possible using the [rviz_animated_view_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_animated_view_controller) plugin. This is a regular RViz plugin, so does not require you to use `librviz` at all, and you interact with it using ROS msgs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2015-03-04**:
Thank you! That did the trick! :)